# online store script which support multi provider

Tags: shopping-cart

Does any one know a online shop script ( php - mysql) which support multi providers?
I want to run a shop and some providers can login and manage their own products / sales and admin can manage all of them.
Providers may create / delete edit own products and can't access to other provider information.

Comment: Hi please have a look at my answer about cs-cart multi vendor edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**X-Cart**](http://www.x-cart.com/features.html) is quality e-commerce software which comes in a Platinum version, which contains Multi-Vendor support.  This includes separate shipping rates for vendors.  As of 23rd Nov 2012 it costs $1795.

Comment: we use X-card from 2004, we try to find better product but I think in it's price range X-card is good choose

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this out. I saw it not too long ago and have not dived too much into it, but this could help you out. http://www.opencart.com/

Comment: opencart does not have multiprovider feature

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to build the site in Magento, which is Open Source and can be installed for free, then create an external application which uses the Magento API, through which each vendor can control his/her own products, stock, orders, etc.

The [Magento API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/support/magento_core_api) uses SOAP. Your external application would be built around a SOAP client and would use SOAP calls to perform its various actions. I strongly recommend building this external application in PHP as the native SoapClient will work pretty much seamlessly with Magento SOAP server.

Answer (score 0):

[Ubercart](http://ubercart.org) is based on Drupal and it's all permission based and you can fine grain as per your requirement. It is powerful but ligher weight than Magento however learning curve is steep.

But I'm not sure whether this type of requirement was kept in mind by the designers of Ubercart.

Answer (score 0):

Actually CS-Cart Multi Vendor is built for this exact purpose so that you can allow vendors to login and sell their own products similar to a market place like Envato and you charge if you want a small fee for each item sold

http://www.cs-cart.com/multivendor.html

> CS-Cart Multi-Vendor is an extended edition of CS-Cart that enables
>   you to create an online marketplace where multiple vendors can manage
>   sales of their own products through one common web store.